# Should I publish the root package created by Lerna

Tags: lerna

Newbie question here. I know I can modify the `package.json` in the root directory of a Lerna monorepo and bundle all packages, but I have seen implementation of making one of the packages to be the final bundled package as well.

My question is, which approach is more favourable? Is there any reason for me to choose one over another?

Comment: Are you using scoped packages? (`@scope/package-name`)

Comment: Yes I do for those inner packages.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a link (for an article or github issue) where the root `package.json` can be modified with lerna?